# Military sidecar era

Tags: 20th-century, military, war

Which is the documented first military (officially issued) sidecar?

Which is the last service sidecar?

Comment: [This article in Military History Monthly](http://www.military-history.org/articles/top-five-military-sidecars.htm) claims 1914 for the Watsonian Sidecar Ambulance and the Scott Mobile Machine Gun, but I don't have a proper source for their claims.

Answer (score 1):

> In 1916 the U.S. Army ordered up some Harleys with sidecars to help track down Pancho Villa in the deserts along the Mexican border, and Bill Harley developed machine-gun mounts for the sidecars. *[Rider magazine](http://ridermagazine.com/2011/05/13/a-short-history-of-sidecars/)*

According to that article the first sidecar was invented between 1893 and 1903; 1916 seems like a plausible date for the first military motorcycle.

"plausible" just means that someone else may find an earlier date.....

Comment: That could be fine for "what's the first" question; no answer, at the moment, as for the last issued sidecar (I don't think someone is still using the vehicle nowadays).

Comment: I think the Russians still build a motorcycle with a side car.